# Mapbox example as a React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to use this [fiddle code from Mapbox](https://jsfiddle.net/5em07c4n/1/) in my react app. Official code [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/animating-flight-paths/)

So far, this is my code, I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'accessToken' of undefined` I am new to React so having a hard time converting this js code. Any resources/codelinks are appreciated for reference. And how can I make mapbox work as a react component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
// import * as d3 from 'd33';
import './StreamGraph.css';
// import 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.js';
// import 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.css';
// import 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js';
// import 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js';
// import 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/arc.js/v0.1.0/arc.js';
// import 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v1.0.0/leaflet.markercluster.js';
// import 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v1.0.0/MarkerCluster.css';
// import 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v1.0.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css';

// import mapbox from 'mapbox';
import 'mapbox';
import 'leaflet';
import arc from 'arc';
import largeAirports from '../data/large_airports_only.csv';
import 'mapbox/lib/mapbox.js';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import 'jquery/src/ajax.js';
import 'ajax/lib/ajax.js';
import 'arc/arc.js';
import 'jquery/src/jquery.js';
import 'mapbox/dist/mapbox-sdk.min.js';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js';
import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css';
import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css';
// import * from 'jquery';


// setting up via node
// var MapboxClient = require('mapbox');
// var client = new MapboxClient('pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FueWFzaW4iLCJhIjoiY2tnbzA2aW9mMGI4cTJybnFvOTVzYm84aCJ9.voOP8PnCpZrEsilFflPswg');


function Mapbox(props) {

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log(largeAirports);

        // feb map for now
        var pairs = [[[47.539123535, -122.30667114299999], [47.539238364, -122.30649508]], [[38.690728656, -121.60168457], [47.54095459, -122.311683655]], [[49.297393799, -123.105046199], [48.41784668, -123.388718825]], [[25.065261065, 121.22915591799999], [22.31350708, 113.906000311]], [[34.422586732, 135.237007141], [25.067138672, 121.23148600299999]], [[49.18676861300001, -123.16721866], [49.17910766600001, -123.14927321200001]], [[22.298858643000003, 113.90620006200001], [25.073966333, 121.21734043299999]]]


        // declaring for the purpose of checking mapbox in react
        var ident_lat = {"KLAX": 47.539123535}
        var ident_lon = {"KLAX": -122.30252}
        var origin_lat = {"KLAX": -122.30252}
        var origin_lon = {"KLAX": -122.30252}
        var dest_lat = {"KLAX": -122.30252}
        var dest_lon = {"KLAX": -122.30252}


        var container = L.DomUtil.get('map');
        if(container != null){
            container._leaflet_id = null;
        }

        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FueWFzaW4iLCJhIjoiY2tnbzA2aW9mMGI4cTJybnFvOTVzYm84aCJ9.voOP8PnCpZrEsilFflPswg';

        // Animation is non-geographical - lines interpolate in the same amount of time regardless of trip length.

        // Show the whole world in this first view.
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
            .setView([20, 0], 2)
            .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9'));

        var credits = L.control.attribution({
        prefix: ''
        }).addTo(map);



        // Disable drag and zoom handlers.
        // Making this effect work with zooming and panning
        // would require a different technique with different
        // tradeoffs.
        map.dragging.disable();
        map.touchZoom.disable();
        map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
        map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
        if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();

        // Transform the short [lat,lng] format in our
        // data into the {x, y} expected by arc.js.
        function obj(ll) { return { y: ll[0], x: ll[1] }; }

        // var select_id = document.getElementById('select');
        // var get_value = select_id.value;
        // var get_ident = name_ident.get(get_value)
        // console.log("get_ident: ", get_ident);
        var counter = 0;

        var get_ident = undefined;

        if (get_ident != undefined){
            // adding marker - airport
            var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(ident_lat.get(get_ident), ident_lon.get(get_ident)), {
                icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol':'airport', 'marker-color': '4587f4'})
                });
                map.addLayer(marker);
        }

    
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        if (ident_lat.has(get_ident)){
            // airport is selected
            origin_lat = pairs[i][0][0].toString()
            origin_lon = pairs[i][0][1].toString()
            dest_lat = pairs[i][1][0].toString()
            dest_lon = pairs[i][1][1].toString()

            if (JSON.stringify([ident_lat.get(get_ident), ident_lon.get(get_ident)]) == JSON.stringify([origin_lat.slice(0,4), origin_lon.slice(0,4)]) || JSON.stringify([ident_lat.get(get_ident), ident_lon.get(get_ident)]) == JSON.stringify([dest_lat.slice(0,4), dest_lon.slice(0,4)])){
                counter = counter + 1;
                // filter it out
                var generator = new arc.GreatCircle(
                obj(pairs[i][0]),
                obj(pairs[i][1]));
                var line = generator.Arc(100, { offset: 100 });
                var newLine = L.polyline(line.geometries[0].coords.map(function(c) {
                return c.reverse();
                }), {
                    color: '#fff',
                    weight: 1,
                    opacity: 0.5
                })
                .addTo(map);
                var totalLength = newLine._path.getTotalLength();
                newLine._path.classList.add('path-start');
                newLine._path.style.strokeDashoffset = totalLength;
                newLine._path.style.strokeDasharray = totalLength;
                setTimeout((function(path) {
                    return function() {
                        path.style.strokeDashoffset = 2; // no animation == 0
                    };
                })(newLine._path), i * 2); // no animation == 0
            }
            console.log("counter: ", counter);
        }
        else if (get_ident == undefined) {
            console.log("else block");
            // Transform each pair into a circle using the Arc.js plugin
            var generator = new arc.GreatCircle(
                    obj(pairs[i][0]),
                    obj(pairs[i][1]));
            var line = generator.Arc(100, { offset: 100 });
            // Leaflet expects [lat,lng] arrays, but a lot of
            // software does the opposite, including arc.js, so flip here.
            var newLine = L.polyline(line.geometries[0].coords.map(function(c) {
                return c.reverse();
            }), {
                color: '#fff',
                weight: 1,
                opacity: 0.5
            })
            .addTo(map);
            var totalLength = newLine._path.getTotalLength();
            newLine._path.classList.add('path-start');
            // This pair of CSS properties hides the line initially
            // See http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/ for details on this trick.
            newLine._path.style.strokeDashoffset = totalLength;
            newLine._path.style.strokeDasharray = totalLength;
            // Offset the timeout here: setTimeout makes a function run after a certain number of milliseconds
            setTimeout((function(path) {
                return function() {
                    // setting the strokeDashoffset to 0 triggers animation
                    path.style.strokeDashoffset = 2;
                };
            })(newLine._path), i * 2);
        }
    }


    });


    return (
        <div className="mapbox_container">
            <div id = "map" className="dark"></div>
        </div>
    )
}   

export default Mapbox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the provided example into a React component by:

1. including mapbox css & js via cdns on index.html

   ```
   <link
      href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
   />
   ```
2. arc.js to make paths curved via cdn on index.html

`<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/arc.js/v0.1.0/arc.js"></script>`

3. normally you could import directly flights variable via this script `<script src='/mapbox.js/assets/data/flights.js'></script>`
   but it does not seem to work so place the json inside a constant (you can try again if it works for you using the above script)
4. Now you have all the libraries you need create a custom Mapbox comp as you did in your example by placing the demo code inside a useEffect :

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import pairs from "./flights.json";

```
L.mapbox.accessToken =
  "pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FueWFzaW4iLCJhIjoiY2tnbzA2aW9mMGI4cTJybnFvOTVzYm84aCJ9.voOP8PnCpZrEsilFflPswg";

export default function Mapbox() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(L.mapbox);

    const map = L.mapbox
      .map("map")
      .setView([20, 0], 2)
      .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer("mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9"));

    L.control
      .attribution({
        prefix:
          '<a href="http://openflights.org/data.html">Flight data from Open Flights, under the ODbL license</a>'
      })
      .addTo(map);

    // Disable drag and zoom handlers.
    // Making this effect work with zooming and panning
    // would require a different technique with different
    // tradeoffs.
    map.dragging.disable();
    map.touchZoom.disable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();

    // Transform the short [lat,lng] format in our
    // data into the {x, y} expected by arc.js.
    function obj(ll) {
      return { y: ll[0], x: ll[1] };
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
      // Transform each pair of coordinates into a pretty
      // great circle using the Arc.js plugin, as included above.
      var generator = new arc.GreatCircle(obj(pairs[i][0]), obj(pairs[i][1]));
      var line = generator.Arc(100, { offset: 10 });
      // Leaflet expects [lat,lng] arrays, but a lot of
      // software does the opposite, including arc.js, so
      // we flip here.
      var newLine = L.polyline(
        line.geometries[0].coords.map(function (c) {
          return c.reverse();
        }),
        {
          color: "#fff",
          weight: 1,
          opacity: 0.5
        }
      ).addTo(map);
      var totalLength = newLine._path.getTotalLength();
      newLine._path.classList.add("path-start");
      // This pair of CSS properties hides the line initially
      // See http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/
      // for details on this trick.
      newLine._path.style.strokeDashoffset = totalLength;
      newLine._path.style.strokeDasharray = totalLength;
      // Offset the timeout here: setTimeout makes a function
      // run after a certain number of milliseconds - in this
      // case we want each flight path to be staggered a bit.
      setTimeout(
        (function (path) {
          return function () {
            // setting the strokeDashoffset to 0 triggers
            // the animation.
            path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
          };
        })(newLine._path),
        i * 100
      );
    }
}, []);

return <div id="map" className="light"></div>;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mapbox-example-as-a-react-component-dnhhn?file=/src/Mapbox.jsx)

Comment: Such a life saviour!!! Thank you for the demo as well. I understood it better now. React seems confusing as I have just started. Also, I am getting this error right now ```Failed to compile - L is not defined and 'arc' is not defined``` I have added the links in index.html and the page that I want my mapbox in, is not homepage, does that makes a difference?

Comment: this occurs because eslint does not find the variables you mention in the specific file but these variables are available because of the cdn import. You need to use npm packages to avoid getting that error but I am not sure all these mapbox packages are available via npm. Some of them they are. If you import the libraries on index.html you should have mapbox available everywhere. Please upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted if it solves your issue.

Comment: Okay. How is it working in codesandbox? I did mark it correct as you explained it very well how to convert the code but I need to figure out package imports. I did ```import L from 'leaflet'`; and import arc from 'arc'; ``` but that does not solve the problem. Now I am getting this error ```TypeError: Cannot set property 'accessToken' of undefined``` if you somehow find about this please let me know. Thanks for solving my problem!

Comment: I did try it to demonstrate you that way but it is quite tricky because I think that for instance mapbox's arc library is not available via npm. At least I didn't find it. If all of the used packages are available via npm then you will have to import both their js and css files, to make the demo functional, either on index.js to have it globally available or on the specific components you need them.

Comment: Okay. I will try that. Isn't this the package for arc.js https://www.npmjs.com/package/arc ?

Comment: yes it seems so. I compared the files and they seem identical. Initially I thought it is mapbox specific library but it seems not. [mapbox arc](https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/arc.js/v0.1.0/arc.js). [arc](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js/blob/gh-pages/arc.js)

Comment: Yes. But again it's not making it work.
I have added these till now ```import L from 'leaflet';
import arc from 'arc';
import 'arc/arc';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.js';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';```

Comment: Did you import mapbox.css, mapbox.js?

Comment: Imported js file using ```import 'mapbox/lib/mapbox.js';``` but there is no css file in the mapbox package. However in mapbox-gl package there is one. I am confused between these two packages.

Comment: You need mapbox not mapbox-gl Here is the [css](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/blob/publisher-production/theme/style.css)

Comment: Cool loaded. Still getting error ```TypeError: Cannot set property 'accessToken' of undefined``` at line ```L.mapbox.accessToken = ...```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with leaflet but, with mapbox-gl, you can set your map as following

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import * as mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";

mapboxgl.accessToken = "your-token-here";

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "map",
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9",
      zoom: 12,
      center: [-122.447303, 37.753574]
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="map" style={{ height: "100vh" }}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

or you can also use react-map-gl like this

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";

export default () => {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = React.useState({
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    longitude: 139.63270819862225,
    latitude: 35.458058995332536,
    zoom: 13.5,
    mapStyle: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
    mapboxApiAccessToken:
      "your-token-here"
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <ReactMapGL {...viewport} onViewportChange={setViewport} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! npm has two packages - mapbox and mapbox-gl. Do we always have to use the later one? And thanks for this snippet.

Comment: You're welcome! we can use either one but i prefer the later one which is easier to setup for simpler map